# Phone call quality suddenly choppy, even though signal is good

Tags: calls, htc-evo

I have a Sprint HTC EVO 4G running the Fresh Gingerbread ROM. The call quality in my apartment has always been great. However, this week the call quality has been extremely choppy to the point of not being usable, no matter how I hold it. I haven't really done anything to the phone or my apartment, even though all its signal bars except one are full.

If I remember correctly I still have good call quality at work, so I don't think its solely a phone issue...

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

Appears to be a Sprint issue - call quality's good again today. The lesson here is that there's always more to call quality than cell signal bars.

Comment: Btw: same applies to network (mobile data) quality. I find myself often with "full bars" but no data (in a specific area)...

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to hear it has been corrected.

Let me add an answer as to why that can happen:  If they install a new tower somewhere, there is always somje adjustment made in the master control system.  For instance, if you are right in the middle between two towers and it detects nearly the same signal level from both towers, it might switch you back and forth with slight changes of your detected signal.

It can slightly change by simply moving the phone to the other ear, or walking around, etc..

Sprint probably fixed it by setting the system to have longer hold times on your initial tower, and perhaps a tweak to their signal-comparison algorithm.

It is those comparison of signals that allow you to be mobile and switch from tower to tower as you move.  Usually it happens so quickly you won't notice.